# Converting information retrieved from linkedin into text and saving it into database

Tags: php, mysql, json, storage, linkedin-api

I have to retrieve data from linkedin using CallAPI function and then store this data into my database.The code is fetching the data in json format even displaying it but the storage part isnt working.

This is my db.php code

```
$check = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->userTable WHERE oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."' AND email = '".$email."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0){
        $result = $check->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $query = "UPDATE $this->userTable SET fname = '".$userdata->firstName."', lname = '".$userdata->lastName."', email = '".$userdata->emailAddress."' WHERE id = ".$result['id'];
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $result['id'];
    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO $this->userTable(oauth_provider,oauth_uid,fname,lname,email,location,country,picture_url,profile_url,created,modified) VALUES('linkedin','".$userdata->id."','".$userdata->firstName."','".$userdata->lastName."','".$userdata->emailAddress."')";
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $this->db->insert_id;
    }
```

The program has an insert query still data isnt being stored anywhere.

Comment: what is the error you are getting while inserting the record ?

Comment: Try `userTable(oauth_provider,oauth_uid,fname,lname,email)` only as your values don't match column count. I'm thinking that might probably be the issue

Answer (score 0):

In you inserting query you are trying to insert 5 values

VALUES('linkedin','".$userdata->id."','".$userdata->firstName."','".$userdata->lastName."','".$userdata->emailAddress."')

in 10 columns:

(oauth_provider,oauth_uid,fname,lname,email,location,country,picture_url,profile_url,created,modified)

So just arrange it to have the same numbers of columns and values to have it work properly